# Any way to get Meteor using a native ACID compliant db?

Tags: postgresql, meteor, transactions, acid, tokumx

I am seriously considering Meteor framework for building every POC and apps in the future...but, I can't get ride of an ACID compliant database as I have few usages of multi-documents atomic transaction that require this compliance.

Meteor strongly rely on MongoDB syntax and storage engine at the moment (it means there are no "Transaction" related syntax available...)

I am currently evaluating any solution allowing this ACID capability :

- Using a MySQL native driver for Meteor (different syntax than MongoDB?)
- Using a PostgreSQL native driver for Meteor (SQL syntax)
- Using a TokuMX (a MongoDB fork with ACID compliance...same syntax than MongoDB appart from transaction related commands that would be required to add)

Those 3 solutions are good candidates for the Meteor roadmap as shown [here](https://trello.com/c/6ugalZMG/54-additional-database-support)

What pros/cons about those solution ? Which are the most advanced one ?
What would you although consider as a solution to keep Meteor while storing documents in a NoSQL like ACID compliant db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally forged my own conclusion...

I will have TWO platforms :

- a Meteor front with business data in PostgreSQL and some front data or easy-to-replicate data in MongoDB
- a Java data backend (server2server only) handling all atomic operations on my business data in PostgreSQL...plus technical adapters (SAP, Salesforce), a BPMN 2.0 workflow engine (Actility), and any registered SOA needed from other systems

Any comments are still very welcomed and will be considered and answered

Answer (score 2):

sqlAndMeteor

If you are like me, you love Meteor but hate Mongo. In Meteor's Trello Roadmap (https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap), the most voted feature is SQL Support, either PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Since there is no date for that in Meteor, here I summarize the partial solutions I have found.

1.- Use SQL only for client-side querys.

Let's face it, Mongo sucks on common data operations, so having the ability to use SQL to query data (with JOINS, GRUP BY and so on) would relief a lot of pain. There are packages which let you use SQL in the client, at least for querys: The simplest one is a old (2010) utility, SqlLike (http://www.thomasfrank.se/sqlike.html). The new player in town is alaSQL, which is actively developed by @agershun (https://github.com/agershun/alasql). The SqlLike advantage is that it only has 10k. AlaSQL, is a lot more powerful, of course, but for using SQL to replace mongo sintax in unions and aggregations, SqlLike is OK.

With both of them you can do something like this in your helper:

```
productsSold:function(){
  var customerSalesHistory=salesHistory.find({cutomerId:Session.get('currentCustomer')}).fetch();
  var items=products.find().fetch();
  return alasql("select item.name, sales.ordered as sumaVentas from ? sales, ? items
      where items.Id=sales.itemId",[customerSalesHistory,items]);
}
```

2.- Experiment with direct SQL support.

Some packages try to replace Mongo (and minimongo) with MySql or PostgreSQL. @numtel's MySql package is Meteor-MySql https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql, and PostgreSQL is Meteor-pg (https://github.com/numtel/meteor-pg). Both are good attempts to solve the problem, but have some issues yet and are somehow cumbersome to adapt.

A team from Hack Reactor has formed Meteor Stream, and its first product is a PostgreSql integration with Meteor, meteor-postgres (https://github.com/meteor-stream/meteor-postgres). It looks very good and uses alaSql on the client to replace minimongo.

Both approaches are good, but they have some problems:

They broke deployment to meteor.
They are very, very young and not near production ready AFAIK
They still require tweaks to the usual pub-sub sintax we are used to, which could raise compatibility issues with other meteor packages.
3.- Still use Mongo, but as simple repository for your MySql database.

This option maintains all Meteor's characteristics and uses Mongo as a temporal repository for your MySql or PostgreSql databases.

A brilliant attempt to that is mysql-shadow by @perak (https://github.com/perak/mysql-shadow). It does what it says, keeps Mongo synchronized both ways with MySql and let's you work your data in MySql.

The bad news is that the developer will not continue maintaining it, but what is done is enough to work with simple scenarios where you don't have complex triggers that update other tables or stuff like that.

For a full featured synchronization you can use SymmetricsDS (http://www.symmetricds.org), a very well tested database replicator. This involves setting up a new java server, of course, but is by far the best way to be sure that you will be able to convert your Mongo database in a simple repository of your real MySql, PostgreSQL, SQL Server , Informix database. I have to check it myself yet.

For now MySQL Shadow seems like a good enough solution.

One advantage of this approach is that you can still use all standard Meteor features, packages, meteor deployment and so on. You don´t have to do anything but set up the synch mechanism, and you are not breaking anything.

Also, if someday the Meteor team uses some of the dollars raised in SQL integration, your app is more likely to work as is.

Comment: Meteor-pg : I think this is a strong part in my answer.
mysql-shadow : since MySQL is bought by Oracle...I think it's dead
SymmetricsDS : too young for my usages
==> Thanks for the long post, I'll post an answer to my final conclusion

Comment: symmetricDS has been around since 2007. BTW you might want to use a  etl package like Kettle from pentaho, but it seems that symmetricds is far easier to configure.

Comment: It looks like symmetricDS may be a good candidate to replicate data between MongoDB and PostgreSQL...as it can be deployed as a classic WAR package in my JAVA SOA platform. Thanks Victor !

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL works for you, I've used the [meteor-mysql](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql) package and it works well.

Comment: In fact, I don't see any future for MySQL since it became an Oracle asset...but the meteor-mysql package looks like a good candidate.